# Need to access a directory from .net website hosted on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an Asp.net website hosted on Azure. It has an upload excel file functionality so a Fileupload control is in play.

```
string fileToSave = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryLocation"] + FileUpload.FileName;
FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileToSave);
```

This works fine in traditional IIS servers but in Azure I am not sure what path to give in for "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryLocation"]".

I have tried some shared location but looks like it cannot access those.

Please give me some direction.

Comment: No one yet ...? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to a web application that is hosted on a local IIS your application can run on several instances in Azure that you do not have control over. It even can be moved to another server under certain circumstances. So using a local file system folder is not an option. Instead, you have to use a store that you can access from all the instances.

Have a look at the following overview of Azure Storage under this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/). Typically, you would store files in a Blob or a File Storage. On this site, you can also find some samples on how to access the storage from the cloud (and later on from an on-premise application that processes the data).

Comment: Okay even if I use blob then I think it will again be a problem because what I am doing with the excel is that I am importing the excel/csv data to SQL table using OleDbDataAdapter. what do you think ?

Comment: Do you need to store the file in a file system or can you process it directly and add the data to the database? In this case, I'd just read the bytes into memory and do all the processing without storing the file. Of course, the import should be reasonably fast.

Comment: umm.. I think it can be processed directly, Let me google and try that then.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work but I would recommend you to store files in blob storage. See https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/